# How do I code my submit button go to an email address

Tags: html

my send an email button isn't working "Here's my html. Does anyone see a problem?

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT EMAIL TO: info@whatshouldisay.ca" <a href="mailto:info@whatshouldisay.ca">
```

Comment: @CTravel The problem has been fixed now: the missing code was added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might use `Form` tag with action attribute to submit the `mailto`.

Here is an example:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com" >
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do an email from HTML. Typically you see people doing a mailto like so:

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com">Click to email</a>
```

But if you are doing it from a button you may want to look into a javascript solution.