# use form input to send the data to an email while also navigating to google to perform the "search"

Tags: php, html, forms, email

i wasn't sure how to best title this. but here is what is what i'm wanting to do:
i have internet explorer opening in kiosk mode to a landing page displaying a list of email providers.

- gmail
- yahoo
- hotmail

i want to add another option that allows the user to input their email address (or something close) and it will act like a normal browser url area and take them to google search so they then access their email. i also want the input to be sent to a designated email so we can add the new email to the list of choices so users will decrease their need to use the "search" input.

from these two pages i found what i need to accomplish (in html) each task individually.

this opens the input to a google search page:
[Is it possible to update a url link based on user text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097573/is-it-possible-to-update-a-url-link-based-on-user-text-input)

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <button type="Submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

this sends an email with the input to an email
[How do I code my submit button go to an email address [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239513/how-do-i-code-my-submit-button-go-to-an-email-address)

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com" >
  <input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
</form>
```

i have no experience in php and just a little with html form elements so, i was not sure if this would work:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <button type="Submit">Search</button> 
</form>
```

or if you can even have a submit button perform two actions.

also, any tips on where to go to get the php code that would help me to accomplish my goal?

Comment: its not php you need, you actually have to use jquery and send an ajax call while preventing the default action. afterwards resume with the submit.

Comment: You can't have two action parameters in your form element.

Comment: Is this sort of what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yf5qmx62/

Comment: more like this - https://jsfiddle.net/h313n/6nLkxyeb/ which is how i need it to work. this works with the exception of sending an email to a designated email address with the "search" term